# Styling Iconic Icon Library with Qt Quick

Tags: qt, svg, icons, qml, qt5

Iconic's SVG based icon library is attractive enough in it's base form.  It is possible to load those icons as is into my Qt Quick application as SVGs with the SVG plug in.

To really harness the potential of the library, though, access to the custom styling features Iconic provides is paramount.  Is there any way to style the iconic icons like they were supposed to be styled on a QML page?  I'm looking at the iconic.js script, but not convinced it will work outside the web world.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I really just need a way to tell the SVG renderer about my desired style.  Or potentially a different SVG renderer than the default that accepts style as an input.

Comment: I ended up making a custom SVG image provider that isable to accept parameters as part of the image name and edit the SVG xml on the fly.  The good, this allows me to do basics like change the fill color in QML.  The bad, I seem to only have TinySVG support with the Qt SVG module I'm using for rendering and a few other c++ SVG libraries.  So no fancy styling as demo'd on the Iconic site.